# auto linking asset files, laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm pretty new to laravel and so far I'm liking it. Due to some situations where I forgot to include my new js or css files into my layout, Im looking for a way to link all files from those folders.

Im totally willing to create this myself, but I'm not sure what is the best way to do this. So far I have registered some serviceproviders, like viewcomposers and helpers. I was thinking I can make another viewcomposer which collects the folders I want, and link it to the desired layout.

But I don't want to create unnecessary functions (which might already exist). I'm hoping you guys can give me some insight in what's possible in laravel, good/bad practice, useful classes to use etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do this.

I would use Elixir (depending on which version of Laravel you are using) to compile and version my assets. This will mean that you only need to include the references to one file CSS file and one JS file in your view.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir

You then just need to maintain your gulpfile.

Versioning your assets also means that you never need to CTRL+F5 to refresh them.

Comment: Tnx for the input, atm I am using webpack.mix to compile my scss files. I was already keeping the style for the login and logged-in pages separated, using a simple auth check and 'else' in the layout. Can I tell the mixer as well to compile some of the files into 1?

Comment: Other then that I'm planning to create a cms for multiple users/ranks with specified/limited page access. I was thinking, maybe I should not include certain javascript files into pages that don't need it. Like sript files that contain ajax requests etc. Or maybe it's not needed to go through this trouble, because I have to validate the requests in php anyway.

Comment: Yes, you can compile and version them all into one. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#vanilla-js